# Right To Left Bracket display wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, right-to-left

When the Label text value ends with end bracket. The result in Right to Left is wrong like example.

```
Text: ABC (123)
Result: (ABC (123
Expected Result: ABC (123)
```

Is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: How are you assigning the text to label, Code ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the Unicode ***`Right-to-left mark`***, (`U+200F`) in your text. Conversely, use the ***`Left-to-right mark`*** (`U+200E) if you know you need LTR rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I found one helpful link http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/control.aspx

Comment: That link no longer works, but this one does: https://web.archive.org/web/20160913021127/microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/control.aspx

Comment: It was unclear from this answer where to put the Right-to-Left mark - the fixed text is "ABC (123)\u200E"

Answer (score 0):

Check your input encoding.you should use UTF family or unicode to gain your goal.
also check your file encoding in visual studio.